# Why do people create directory structures like edu.mit.stk in Java?

Tags: java

My question is why do people create directory structures with at least one folder named edu, and then another single folder named mit (for example), followed by all their code in a subfolder?

Is this some sort of identifier?

Is the structure actually used by the computer for any reason - or is it just used to help the reader?

If so, how so does it help the reader?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/index.html

Comment: Here comes the flood of duplicate answers...

Comment: @SteveKuo They're all good - just waiting on the timer now.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is done to prevent name collisions.  The default rule is to use the reverse of your domain name as the package structure

Thus   Google would keep all their code in `com.google.*` packages while Microsoft would keep their code in `com.microsoft.*` packages.  Then, if both companies implement a SearchEngine class, you won't have a naming collision.

Educational institutions do the same thing, so you know that any code in an `edu.mit.*` subpackage was likely developed by a group at [MIT](http://www.mit.edu)

Answer (score 4):

The Java convention is to arrange source directories to match the package hierarchy.  See e.g. [*Managing Source and Class Files*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/managingfiles.html).

So if you have a class `edu.mit.stk.Foo`, then it will be located as `edu/mit/stk/Foo.java`.

Answer (score 2):

It's a namespace.  It prevents class/package name collisions.  Typically it's the company's domain name in reverse (e.g. `com.ibm.PackageName`) , but its value is arbitrary and can be anything.

Answer (score 0):

By convention Java package names follow the domain naming convention in reverse order. Thus `edu.mit` is an appropriate prefix for a package developed at [`mit.edu`](http://mit.edu/).

Answer (score 0):

to match with package convention (look like reversed Internet domain name).

you can see more details at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/namingpkgs.html

Answer (score 0):

Packages are named using their reversed internet domain names to avoid name conflicts. So a calss from ecliplse may be in a `package com.eclipse.XYZClass`

From [Naming a package](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/namingpkgs.html):

> Companies use their reversed Internet domain name to begin their
>   package names—for example, com.example.mypackage for a package named
>   mypackage created by a programmer at example.com.

To be identified properly, a package should be in a flder with the same name. So if you have a class in `com.madbreaks.MyClass`, you will have the folder structure as

```
com
|
+--madbreaks
   |   
   +---MyClass
```

See also: the [Java tutorial on packages](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/index.html).